# How do I pass an array for more than one series of random x-y data to Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create a multiple series version of this: http://jsfiddle.net/j5qzcu68/2/

The random generator for this works fine for one series:

```
events: {
             load: function () {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function () {
                       var x1 = Math.random(),
                           y1 = Math.random(),
                           x2 = Math.random(),
                           y2 = Math.random();

                        series.addPoint([x1, y1], true, true);
                 }, 1000);
              }
            }
```

My effort to pass two series of x-y values is this: http://jsfiddle.net/j5qzcu68/6/
HTML

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'scatter',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function () {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function () {
                            var x1 = Math.random();
                                y1 = Math.random();
                                x2 = Math.random();
                                y2 = Math.random();
                             series.addPoint([[x1, y1], [x2, y2]], true, true);
                        }, 1000, true);
                    }  //load function
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Random data'
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 1,
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 1,
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },

            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Fish1',
                data: [0, 0]
            }, {
                name: 'Fish2',
                data: [0, 0]
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Adapting the addPoint method to the following doesn't work:

```
series.addPoint([[x1, y1], [x2, y2]], true, true);
```

Do I need to wade into JSON pre-processing or is there a simple answer on how to pass this array for multiple series?

Comment: How is this related to Java?

Comment: you may need to add two different points like `series.addPoint([x1, y1], true, true); series.addPoint([x2, y2], true, true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use two series and refer to them separaterely.

```
setInterval(function () {
                        var x1 = Math.random();
                            y1 = Math.random();
                            x2 = Math.random();
                            y2 = Math.random();
                         serie1.addPoint([x1, y1], false, true);
                         serie2.addPoint([x2, y2],true,true);
}, 1000, true);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/j5qzcu68/8/

Comment: Perfect response. I have no reputation to upvote you but would have done. :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add two different points like

`series.addPoint([x1, y1], true, true); 
series.addPoint([x2, y2], true, true);`

Comment: Thank you, that clears it up. I have no reputation to upvote you but would have done. :)